# How to make my 4 1/2 yr son understand of why I work/overtime

Tags: pre-schooler, education

Recently I had been too busy with work and my son asked me to 'Play with him' during working from home and I said I am at work so I get free I will, he kept on asking 'R u working so you can buy me toys'? I don't know where he got the concept but I think It is not right to feed him that 'yes I am working to get buy you toys' because it is same like saying to him 'I m working so I can pay bills' when he doesn't have an understanding of how the world works and I do not want him to grow up that even he doesn't want to work in a job he doesn't like he has to, to earn bread and butter.

Or am I thinking too much? I like to rephrase things I say to my son so he grows up not being materialistic and working for things is sort of materialistic for me as I choose my career out of passion and despite so many failures I love and grow with it.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that the most important thing your son wants to hear as a response is *That I spend a lot of time working is not a rejection of you; I love you and I cherish the time we spent together*.

That said, *one important reason why people work is to be able to buy stuff* is a basic fact about the how the world works. The question of how to chose a fulfilling career is not going to be accessible to your son yet. It is probably a good idea to deemphasize the role of buying toys in particular, otherwise you may be asked to deliver on that aspect more often that you'd like, and I could imagine that this could constitute an unwanted push towards a more materialistic worldview.

Your son may or may not have any interest in what *parent is working* means beyond the first paragraph. If he does care, and your work is something you can explain, you can of course try to explain the importance of your work a bit. But be careful with the first part here - it would not be unexpected of a four year old to hear *I work as a pediatrician to cure these kids* as *parent loves these strange kids more than me*. In a few years, he will be better equipped to understand concerns beyond is own daily reality.